# Deadlock when closing a pipe fd

Tags: c++, windows, posix, pipe

I am porting some Unix code to Windows which redirects stderr and stdout to a pipe that I created and there's a thread which reads from this pipe and then sends the output to the debug console.  This works fine on Unix, but I can't get it working on Windows.  The problem occurs when the read side of the pipe is closed.  Instead of writing EOF to the pipe which would cause the thread to quit, it deadlocks.  Why?

One workaround is to skip the call to close, which worries me a little, but since my process is short lived, maybe it isn't a big deal?

Here is sample code which illustrates the problem...   I'm using VS 2010:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#define posix_open _open
#define posix_read _read
#define posix_write _write
#define posix_pipe( fds ) _pipe( fds, 8096, _O_BINARY)
#define posix_close _close
#define posix_dup _dup
#define posix_dup2 _dup2
#define posix_fileno _fileno

using namespace std;

static const int PIPE_READ  = 0;
static const int PIPE_WRITE = 1;

DWORD __stdcall PipeReaderFunc(void* readFd)  
{  
    int pipeFd = *((int*)readFd);
    vector< char > buffer(8096);
    while( posix_read(pipeFd, &buffer[0], buffer.size() ) != 0 )
    {
        OutputDebugString( &buffer[0] );
    }
    return 0;
} 

void test() 
{
    int pipefd[2] = {-1,-1};
    if( posix_pipe( pipefd ) < 0 )
    { throw std::exception( "Failed to initialize pipe." );}

    int stdoutOrig = posix_dup( _fileno(stdout) );
    int stderrOrig = posix_dup( _fileno(stderr) );
    if( -1 == posix_dup2( pipefd[PIPE_WRITE], posix_fileno(stdout) ) ) // closes stdout
    {throw exception( "Failed to dup stdout fd." );}

    if( -1 == posix_dup2( pipefd[PIPE_WRITE], posix_fileno(stderr) ) ) // closes stderr
    {throw exception( "Failed to dup stderr fd." );}

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, PipeReaderFunc, &pipefd[PIPE_READ], 0, NULL); 
    if( NULL == hThread )
    {throw exception("Failed to create thread");}

    cout << "This should go to the debug console" << endl;
    Sleep(1000); // Give time for the thread to read from the pipe

    posix_close( stdoutOrig ); 
    posix_close( stderrOrig ); 
    posix_close( pipefd[PIPE_WRITE] );

    // Deadlock occurs on this line
    posix_close( pipefd[PIPE_READ] );

    // This is commented out because it has no effect right now.
    //WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try 
    { test(); } 
    catch( exception& ex ) 
    { cerr << ex.what() << endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any ideas on how to resolve this!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the `_read` implementation on windows returns -1 when `_close` is called while it is blocked. If it is called after your `_close` completes, it should return -1 as per the documentation. So, it looks like your thread would get stuck in the main loop, because it only terminates when the return value is zero. Maybe you should change your loop condition from `!= 0` to `> 0` and try it.

---

EDIT:

I was looking at the wrong part of the documentation. According to the documentation, the handle from pipe is closed when all descriptors pointing to it are closed. I think you wanted to implement that, but made a small error. If you replace:

```
posix_close( stdoutOrig ); 
posix_close( stderrOrig );
```

with

```
posix_close( posix_fileno(stdout) );
posix_close( posix_fileno(stderr) );
```

the program executes and terminates correctly. This is because there are two fds pointing to the reader handle, and you were closing only one. So the thread was happily blocked, waiting for more data. When you also close the `dup`ed handle, the `read` returns zero (as you've pointed out), and the thread terminates.

Comment: Ah yes, this is correct. On Unix you get EOF when the read end of the pipe is closed. On Windows you don't get EOF until all the fds that refer to the pipe are closed and I wasn't closing them all. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you were using `fork()` and one of the `exec*()` family of functions on Unix instead of `CreateThread()` on Windows, the child process would close the read and write ends of the pipe after doing the `dup2()` operations and before doing the exec.  The parent process would close whichever end of the pipe it was not going to use.  This is necessary (in general) to ensure that there are no stray open file descriptors referring to the pipe.  If there is a stray open write end to the pipe, the reader(s) on the pipe will never get EOF.  If there is a stray open read end to the pipe, the writer may block (deadlock) waiting for a reader read the data - even if that reader is the same process that is doing the writing.

By analogy, you should ensure that your thread has only the ends of the pipe that it needs open, and should close all the other parts.